# Date Stamp on one criteria within Picklist

Tags: formula, datetime, formula-field

I need some help

Aim – When stage = ’Declined’ populate a field called “Declined date” with the date that declined was selected

Field: Stage

Data type : Picklist

I know how to create a workflow on any value within a picklist but  I never created a workflow based on one criteria within the picklist , can this be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the "Formula" entry for the workflow entry criteria.

When you are creating the workflow, change the rule entry to Formula Evaluates to true - and then use the formula function ISPICKVAL.

[image: formula entry]

In your case, enter the formula

```
   ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Declined')
```

like so

[image: formula]

This means your workflow will only be executed on records when this pikclist value equals your string literal.

ISPICKVAL is defined as:

> ISPICKVAL(picklist_field, text_literal) Checks whether the value of a
>   picklist field is equal to a string literal

And further information on it can be found [in the documentation here.](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US)

Once you have set up your entry criteria for this workflow, you will need to make a new "Field Update" action for the process. Click this in the immediate actions area.

[image: field update]

What you want to do is update your date field, so select it from the drop down, and then, in a second, the "Value" section appears, switch to formula view again and enter "NOW()" like so:

[image: date now]

Save your action, save your rule **activate the workflow!!!** and you should be roughly good to go?

Comment: Hi Simon 

I got to that bit. So now i guess i need to go 
create - workflow & approvals -- > field updates 
New field update
And select field i want to update ?

Comment: erm. ok! I will chuck a couple of screenshots on that process in my answer for you. When you said you knew how to create a workflow for "any picklist" value, I assumed that meant you knew how to create workflow, sorry!

Comment: My apologises. I have been thrown in the deep end at work, picking up little pieces of work.